# PowerBI Filter on several text columns and then produce an average %

Tags: powerbi, multiple-columns

I'm trying to take 10 columns that have text in them, filter them all at once based on text, count them, then produce an average.

Text in each column is:  On-Site, TW, RDO, Not Set

I have created the following measure.

```
Monday On-Site = CALCULATE(count('Telework-NEW'[MON]),FILTER(all('Telework-NEW'), [MON] = "On-Site"))
```

What I don't want to do is do this ten times, then add them together, divide by 10 to get my answer.

I've searched the internet, but I must not be asking this correctly.

Sample Data, attached.[image]

The results will be displayed in a card as a percentage.

I hope all this make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well I figured it out with some additional searching.

What I did was to create a new table with the data:

```
Work Schedule = all ('Telework-NEW'[Name Last], 'Telework-NEW'[Name First],'Telework-NEW'[MON], 'Telework-NEW'[TUES], 'Telework-NEW'[WED], 'Telework-NEW'[THUR], 'Telework-NEW'[FRI], 'Telework-NEW'[MON_2], 'Telework-NEW'[TUES_3], 'Telework-NEW'[WED_4], 'Telework-NEW'[THUR_5], 'Telework-NEW'[FRI_6], 'Telework-NEW'[DOD ID (EDIPI)])
```

Then I created a new column that would provide a count of how many times each line had the text "On-Site" in it and divided it by 10, using the following:

```
Average # On-Site = (if(('Work Schedule'[MON])="On-Site",1,0)
+if(('Work Schedule'[TUES])="On-Site",1,0)
+if(('Work Schedule'[WED])="On-site",1,0)
+if(('Work Schedule'[THUR])="On-site",1,0)
+if(('Work Schedule'[FRI])="On-site",1,0)
+if(('Work Schedule'[MON_2])="On-site",1,0)
+if(('Work Schedule'[TUES_3])="On-site",1,0)
+if(('Work Schedule'[WED_4])="On-site",1,0)
+if(('Work Schedule'[THUR_5])="On-site",1,0)
+if(('Work Schedule'[FRI_6])="On-site",1,0)) / 10
```

I then put this answer in a card.